# Finite Morphisms between Varieties have Finite Fibers

Tags: commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

My question refers to following previous thread:
[Geometric interpretation of the Noether normalization lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653113/geometric-interpretation-of-the-noether-normalization-lemma)

Obviously the core problem is: If $X= Spec(A), Y= Spec(R)$ are affine varieties and $\phi: X \to Y$ is a ***finite*** surjective morphism (so equivalently $A$ is a finite $R$-module)

why $\phi$ has finite fibers, so if $P \in Y$ why is $\phi^{-1}(P)$ finite?

Using again the language of commutative algebra the problem boils down to following:

Let $R$ wlog local with maximal ideal $p$ (in general case: localize $R$ by at $p$). We then get a morphism $R/p \to A/pA$.

I want to know why is $A/pA$ is ***finite dimensional*** $R/p$-vector space.

Following the thread [The fibers of a finite morphism of affine varieties are all finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112345/the-fibers-of-a-finite-morphism-of-affine-varieties-are-all-finite)

it suffice to prove that. But I don't see why it holds, so why is $A/pA$ is finite dimensional $R/p$-vector space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is a finite $R$-module, it is generated as an $R$-module by some elements $a_1, \dots, a_n$.  Then $A/pA$ is spanned as an $R/p$-vector space by the images of the $a_i$.

Comment: ah yes of course, and from here to realize that $\phi^{-1}(p)= Spec(A/pA)$ is finite that suffice to observe that $A/pA$ is Artin (and that's because it's finite dimensional VR space... I guess there was a characterisation like that...)